# Differences between grep, fgrep and egrep

Tags: command-line, grep

What are the differences between  [grep](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/grep.1.html), `fgrep` and `egrep`? What are some examples of using them differently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See `man grep`:

> The  variant  programs  `egrep`,  `fgrep`  and  `rgrep` are the same as `grep -E`, `grep -F`, and `grep -r`, respectively. These variants are deprecated, but are provided for backward compatibility.

And

```
Pattern Syntax
   -E, --extended-regexp
          Interpret PATTERNS as extended regular expressions (EREs, see below).

   -F, --fixed-strings
          Interpret PATTERNS as fixed strings, not regular expressions.

   -G, --basic-regexp
          Interpret PATTERNS as basic regular expressions (BREs, see below).  
          This is the default.

   -P, --perl-regexp
          Interpret PATTERNS as Perl-compatible regular expressions (PCREs).  
          This option is experimental when combined with  the  -z  (--null-data)
          option, and grep -P may warn of unimplemented features.
```

---

- Prefer `grep -F` whenever you have no pattern to match as it is a lot faster.
- Use `grep -E` and especially `grep -P` only when Basic Regex does not fullfil your needs as the matching will be slower.

Answer (score 2):

[What's Difference Between Grep, Egrep and Fgrep in Linux? - TecMint](https://www.tecmint.com/difference-between-grep-egrep-and-fgrep-in-linux/) explains the difference well. All three do the same thing with the same code, but have different options.

`egrep` is the same as [`grep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/grep.1.html)`-E`, interpreting **PATTERN** as an [extended regular expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Basic-vs-Extended.html). It treats meta-characters as is and doesn't substitute them as strings like in the original `grep`.  GNU's `grep`, which is used by Ubuntu, has  no  difference in available functionality between basic and extended syntax (unlike the original `grep` found in some other distros).

`fgrep` is the same as [`grep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/grep.1.html)`-F`. interpreting **PATTERN**  as  a  list  of fixed strings (instead of regular expressions), separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched. It doesn't recognize regular expressions, nor any meta-characters. For searching any direct string, it's faster, so this is the version of `grep` which should be selected.